# How to make a file run automatically after download

Tags: download, web

I have made a batch file. I want to run that file immediately after download from my website without user prompt. Any help?

Comment: are you asking us how to write a virus?

Comment: It is just for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some hacks to do that but I would recommend you do not pursue that avenue as it is a significant security risk to your users. If you can configure their machine to automatically run your code, in theory it could be configured to run anyone's code. Not a pleasant thought.